# Salesforce HTML Area Home page component not working

Tags: html, home-page-component, home-page-layout, html-area-component

I have below component enabled for a particular profile Users to navigate to a VF page after the users logs in removing their Home Page. It works fine when I log in from System Admin profile and then log in with the particular User. But during direct login it fails. Come someone let me know the reason and how to overcome it?

**HTML Area Component Code:**

```
Under script tag with language="JavaScript"
window.location.replace("/apex/PASSWORDMGR");
```